# Laravel with VueJS 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have the issue when I fetch states with VueJs.

```
  getStates(){
                axios.get("/api/employees/"+ this.form.country_id + "/states")
                    .then(res => {
                        this.states = res.data
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.error(error.response.data)
                    })
            }
```

This api.php .

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Api\EmployeeDataController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/employees/countries',        [EmployeeDataController::class, 'countries']);
Route::get('/employees/{country}/states', [EmployeeDataController::class, 'states']);
Route::get('/employees/departments',      [EmployeeDataController::class, 'departments']);
Route::get('/employees/{state}/cities',   [EmployeeDataController::class, 'cities']);
```

This is EmployeeDataController contains:

```
public function states(Country $country)
    {
        return response()->json($country->states);
    }
```

This is country model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['country_code', 'name'];

    public function states()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(States::class);
    }
}
```

This is create.vue blade which I store datas.

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="country" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">Country</label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
             <select v-model="form.country_id" @change="getStates()" name="country" class="form-control" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option v-for="country in countries" :key="country.id" :value="country.id">{{country.name}}</option>
            </select>
                 </div>
                    </div>
```

This create form that when I tapped select country, automatically state must fill with state data which I want to fetch.

[image: form]

But I have face to 500 internal server error

[image]

I hope to explain my issue.

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear, it cannot find `App\Models\States`, do you have that class? Share the code, please

Comment: It is interesting that why error happen in this part)). I have not states class. I have State model class State extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['country_id', 'name'];

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }

    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(City::class);
    }
}

Comment: Other  get methods like Route::get('/employees/countries',        [EmployeeDataController::class, 'countries']);  works good.

Comment: Bro... add `use App\Models\States;` on your Country model top.

Comment: Charlie it is not relative with model. There is relationship that country have states. The code must find country's states but doesn't get to the data.

Comment: If country has states, states needs a relation to country, so you should definitely try @Charlie solution. If that does not work, we're going to need to see some more code, like what is the `States` class?

Comment: Definitely didn't work. This is not solution of the issue.I also try to find why appear the **States** class error.

Comment: Have you tried? Your relation is build by `States::class` which means your relation build with `States` model, and there is no use in your country model.

Comment: Please check your file name and class name of States model correctly, is it ```States```?

Comment: I think, your file name is ```States.php```, but  class name ```State```. Both of them will be same.

Comment: @bluestar0505 I find the issue. My issue was that  I wrote states:class instead of state::class. Code must write like `return $this->hasMany(State::class);`